# Linux service 'named' is not functional - is that an issue?

Tags: linux, services, redhat-enterprise-linux

One of the dedicated servers that I have does not seem to have the service 'named' functional:

```
root@server2 [~]# service named start
Locating /var/named/chroot//etc/named.conf failed:
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Note that the double slashes (//) ARE part of the output as well as the long gap before [FAILED] appears.

This 'named' service not being functional is not a problem which is preventing the server / the application on it from working, but I'm wondering if this is a serious issue?

There are entries in /etc/resolv.conf though.

Comment: Are you intending on using the machine as a DNS server?

Comment: Hi Ignacio - no, not at all...

Comment: Unless you're using it as a name server, you don't need named. I suspect it was just never installed because it's not needed.  Ignacio, you might post that as an answer to Matt can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [the Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/) on,
[Security Quick-Start HOWTO for Red Hat Linux](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Security-Quickstart-Redhat-HOWTO/index.html):
Step 1: [**Which services do we really need**](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Security-Quickstart-Redhat-HOWTO/services.html)?

> BIND (named) - This often is installed by default, but is only really needed if you are an authoritative name server for a domain. If you are not sure what this means, then you definitely don't need it.
>   BIND is probably the number one crack target on the Internet.
>   BIND is often used though in a "caching" only mode.
>   This can be quite useful, but does not require full exposure to the Internet.
>   In other words, it should be restricted or firewalled.

<sup>And, if you really want to use a [caching DNS](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch18_:_Configuring_DNS), I guess `BIND 9` should also be checked.</sup>

Comment: No, not at all in this case... so I guess the failed message is good enough for me!